# How can I get the current SIM number in iPhone?

Tags: ios

I know that unlike the operator name and the country code, it's not possible to get the user's phone number in iOS programmatically (at least not with publicly available APIs).

But I have just tried the app **Lyft** and it is autosuggesting my current phone number. I want to know how this app is doing that.

[image: screenshot of the autosuggestion of a phone number in the Lyft app]

Comment: That suggestion is coming from the iOS itself, not from the app.

Comment: The keyboard displays recent text you entered. Since it is a phone pad, it is displaying the mobile number which you might have used recently.

Comment: How to enable this ? Because in app like WhatsApp and other popular app we don get this suggestion , so how it is enabled in Lift App

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phone number suggestion appearing above the keyboard is a built-in iOS feature and it works if a **Text Content Type** is set for a `UITextField`.

Since iOS 10, you can provide a content type for your inputs. iOS then will recommend autofill options for the given content type.

You can set up a content type...

- in Interface Builder by navigating to the **Text Input Traits** section of **the Attributes inspector** (the fourth icon from the right in the top sidebar):

  [image: Attributes inspectior/Text Input Traits/Content Type]
- ...or programmatically with:

  ```
  textField.textContentType = .telephoneNumber
  ```

Comment: I have disabled Auto correction ,predictive and all other feature from keyboards settings from iOS system settings . Why it is suggesting it only lift app not any other app

Comment: @MotiHula Like my answer says, it's likely because Lyft developers selected a text context type for that particular text field.